# VB.NET add databinding to textbox control

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

How do you create a databinding into a textbox that is created at runtime?

Code that created my textbox control

```
    Private Function ADD_TEXTBOX_CONTROL(ByVal ParentControl As Control,
                                     ByVal Name As String,
                                     ByVal Text As String,
                                     ByVal Width As Integer,
                                     ByVal Pos_X As Integer,
                                     ByVal Pos_Y As Integer,
                                     ByVal oNewControlTooltip As String) As TextBox

    Dim oTB As New TextBox

    oTB.Name = Name
    oTB.Text = Text
    oTB.Width = Width
    oTB.Location = New Drawing.Point(Pos_X, Pos_Y)

    ParentControl.Controls.Add(oTB)

    Return oTB

End Function
```

Lets say i would want to bind this textbox with a class property created in the namespace. So that if my textbox value changes, the Body_Cilinder.Height is adjusted as well.

```
Namespace BODY_NAMESPACE

' Class that defines all the Cilinders properties for easy access.
Class Body_Cilinder

    ' Counter to determinate the cilinder quantity required.
    Public Shared Count As Integer = 0

    ' Property decalration fir cilinder properties
    Private _Index As Integer
    Private _Elevation As Double
    Private _Height As Double

    ' Cilinder Index number As Integer for finding the position.
    Public Property Index() As Integer
        Get
            Index = _Index
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Index = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Cilinder Elevation to define the cilinder elevation from the T.L.
    Public Property Elevation() As Double
        Get
            Elevation = _Elevation
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Elevation = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Cilinder Height to define the cilinder height.
    Public Property Height() As Double
        Get
            Height = _Height
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Height = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Add Cilinder count every-time a new "Body Cilinder" instance Is created
    Public Sub New()
        Count = Count + 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

End Namespace

What do I need to add?
I found this example but I don't quite get how it functions

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add _
   (New Binding("Text", ds, "customers.custName"))
```

[Link to source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Its a mapping operation.  The TextBox1.Text gets its data from the "custName" field in the "customers" DataTable in the DataSet. `ds`.  Likewise changes to the textbox 'flow' back to a database the same way.  I am not sure it applies to your code

Comment: Do you maybe know of a better way to do this? or is it not possible like this?

Comment: `textBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", cylinderObject, "Height"))` You'll have to rebuild/reset for each instance.  Alternatively, you could just use the Enter and Leave events to update the object (simpler)

Comment: And how would you suggest to update the object? How do I write this? Is this a simple command or do I need to get the sender it's binding object to do this?