# VB.NET pass object to new windows form

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I have a datagridview that displays all the objects in my collection. The objects displayed are in the base class. But there are in fact +- 8 different derived classes.

For the user to add object specific information to the object I open a new form when the user double clicks the row `Dim x As New Cylinder_form` `x.Show()` that will have extra fields to add the specific information.

My problem now is, how do I pass the selected object by double click of the user to the new form? I don't have any idea how to do this. First I thought it would be a little like working with subs and functions `Byval` `Byref`. Or I could make a public variable to hold the selected object and reference that variable from my new form?

What is the most common practice to do this?

[image: Datagridview control]

Comment: Pass the object underlying your row to the new form in the Form constructor, get it on the form side and use it for editing. Nothing new here, if you just make a search with 'passing objects to another form'

Comment: If you have 8 distinct classes then you probably ought to have 8 distinct forms.  Each making the properties of such a class editable.  It is the most straight-forward solution.  Look for ways to shrink that number down, a form might well be able to edit more than 1 class by simply hiding or disabling a control.  Maybe a PropertyGrid is good enough.  We can't guess.

Comment: Okay, thank you, by the `Form constructor` you mean in the sub `Public Sub New()`?

Comment: @HansPassant for the 8 classes it would take about 4 distinct forms. The propertygrid is better than what I have now, please clarify.

Comment: This set of questions is (too) [eerily familiar to the set this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34813553/1070452) is from.  Use the DGV like a header display showing the base class props.  Pass them to a PropertyGrid to edit the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to your main problem, passing objects between several forms, would be to pass a instantiated object to the constructor of the editing form, change all properties on save and then continue as normal.
Example:
in your Mainform as a Handler for your CylinderAdd:

```
Sub addCylinder() Handles btCylinder.Click
        Dim cylinder As New Cylinder
        Dim sw As New ShapeWindow(cylinder)
        'blocks mainUI until edit is conformed
        sw.showDialog()
        'Use Object however you want in your mainform
End Sub
```

and in your form that is used to set the properties you create a constructor like this:

```
Sub New(obj As Cylinder)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    'use your shape if it had meaningful default values to initialize form fields
End Sub
```

The example only shows how to do it for an entirely new object, if you already have the object (for example in your datagrid) and just want to edit it, just adjust the code accordingly.

Regarding the proposed propertygrid of Hans Passant, try read this [link on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid) or try take a look at msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Alternatively, if you are familiar with working with reflection and would like to have a bit more influence on the optical appearance of the properties form you can use reflection to obtain all public properties of you figure objects and build your UI in a pure programmatic way, but that is up to your preferences of course, generally a property grid should be sufficient if you build your objects accordingly.

Anyway whether you use a propertygrid or reflection you can do all figures in one window afterwords

Answer (score 2):

Given a `MustInherit` base class with the common properties, several child classes with the props for the more specific types and a `BindingList` to store them and display them in a `DataGridView`,  a `PropertyGrid` would work great to edit these.

For this, the DGV would display them and apparently let the user reorder them by drag and drop (as per a previous question).  Stored as `BaseShape`, then DGV wont display the more specific type properties, but it can act as a "Selector".

For this, you could use the `RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick` event as the signal to edit that item:

```
Dim shapeObj = CType(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, BaseShape)
Dim thisShape = shapeList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Index = shapeObj.Index)

If thisShape IsNot Nothing Then
    propGrid.SelectedObject = thisShape
End If
```

This uses the index property to get the correct item from the underlying list, then display it in the `PropertyGrid`.  I suspect `Index` means "Sequence" and perhaps they change when the rows are dragged and dropped.  If so, I would also have some sort of immutable ID property so each object can be uniquely identified.

The result:

[image]

If you have a DONE button you can add this to force the properties to refresh:

```
propGrid.SelectedObject = Nothing
shapeList.ResetBindings()
```

The thing which makes this extraordinarily simple is that edits to the object in the PropertyGrid automatically flow thru to the list and `DataGridView`.  You dont have to pass an object to something else or design special forms.  As can be seen, you can control a fair amount of how it is displayed using `Attributes`: some are read-only and they are categorized. Any "system" properties such as an Id or perhaps the Index could be easily hidden from view as well.

If you wanted a way to cancel/discard prop grid edits, clone the selected object, display it and then replace the existing item in the List.

This could also be used to define new shapes to be added. When the user selects "New Pyramid" from a Combo, create one and display it in the PropertyGrid for them to edit.  When done, add it to the list for display in the DGV.